# SharePoint docuemnt library Views - If i change view in one area in changes in all

Tags: sharepoint-online, library

How do I show different views in different pages. And how do I lock the views in each area? Currently if I change the view in one spot it changes in all areas of the site

Comment: Hi Michaele, can you mention the version of SharePoint, please? Are you using modern or classic pages?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to have different views on different pages we simply need to create a separate view per page.

- Navigate to your library.
- Create multiple views. Give them descriptive names.
- Navigate to your pages and add a list/library webpart.
- Select one of the views you have created earlier.
- If you are using the classic UI, avoid modifying the views from the page. Always update the view from the library first.

Answer (score 0):

Denis's reply is correct. Just to add some examples for both classic UI and Modern Page. After you added required Views, add the document library web part and change the web part to use different views.

Classic UI:
[image]

Modern UI:
[image]